# Threads states logger Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, winapi, visual-studio-2008

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2008 to log, for example, in Output window, threads state changes. For example, I have 3 threads, Main thread and two worker threads, and I want at a particular time to see a log that contain state changes of those threads, it might look like:

```
7/9/2013 16:38:10 Thread1 Running -> Suspended
7/9/2013 16:38:11 Thread2 Running -> Suspended
7/9/2013 16:38:23 Thread1 Suspended -> Running
7/9/2013 16:38:27 Thread1 Running -> Aborted
7/9/2013 16:38:16 Thread2 Suspended -> Stopped
```

Is it possible to achieve such results using default Visual Studio tools, and if no, are there any third party tools that can do this?

P.S. I'm searching solution for native code (C++) on Windows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not natively, no.  Your thread code would have to call the `OutputDebugString()` function whenever it changes its logical state, otherwise your app would have to hook the `SuspendThread()`, `ResumeThread()` and `ExitThread()` functions directly, such as with detours, and the log when they are called.